# Why double d = FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX; get a result of inf in c language

Tags: c

As a result of the following code, why get an inf?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main()
{
    printf("FLT_MAX = %e\n", FLT_MAX);
    double d = FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX;
    printf("FLT_MAX * 2 = %e\n", d);
    return 0;
}
//Output:

//FLT_MAX = 3.402823e+38
//FLT_MAX * 2 = inf
```

The following code can get the right answer, but I don't know why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main()
{
    printf("FLT_MAX = %e\n", FLT_MAX);
    double d = (double)FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX;
    printf("FLT_MAX * 2 = %e\n", d);
    return 0;
}

//Output:

//FLT_MAX = 3.402823e+38
//FLT_MAX * 2 = 6.805647e+38
```

explain the code behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is float variable auto-promoted to double type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118738/how-is-float-variable-auto-promoted-to-double-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant `FLT_MAX` has type `float`.  This means both operands of the expression `FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX` also have this type, and the result is of type `float`.  And since the result of this addition is greater than what can be stored in type `float`, it results in a value of infinity.

In contrast, the expression `(double)FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX` has one operand of type `double` and one of type `float`.  Because the operands have different types, a common type must be used.  In this case, the `float` operand is converted to `double` and the result of the `+` operator has type `double`.  And since the result can be stored in a `double`, you get a non-infinite value.

Comment: The last two sentences are not entirely correct. It is due to the fact that the first operand being a `double` that type promotion of the second operand to `double` **has** to occur before the expression `FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX` is evaluated, with the result of that entire expression then naturally being `double` as well. Only then the type of the place expression comes into effect (no surprises here, its also a `double`)

Comment: @user2722968 I thought I stated that.  Reworded to clarify.

Comment: Many thx, type promotion on arithmetic operation works.