# Confusion with simple math in C++

Tags: c++, math

I was playing around with C++ today and this is what I found after doing some tests:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myInt = 100;

    int myInt2 = myInt + (0.5 * 17); // the math inside the parentheses should go first

    int difference = myInt2 - myInt; // get the difference of the two numbers

    cout << difference << endl; // difference is 8
}
```

the output is 8

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myInt = 100;

    int myInt2 = myInt - (0.5 * 17); // the math inside the parentheses should still go first

    int difference = myInt - myInt2; // get the difference of the two numbers

    cout << difference << endl; // difference is 9?
}
```

The output is 9?

So according to my first code sample, 0.5 * 17 = 8, but according to my second code sample, 0.5 * 17 = 9. I am aware that I would get the same results without the parentheses, but I am using them to help illustrate what I am doing in my code.

To help narrow down the problem, I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myInt = 100;

    int myInt2 = 0.5 * 17; // use a variable instead of parentheses

    int myInt3 = myInt + myInt2;

    int difference = myInt3 - myInt; // get the difference of the two numbers

    cout << difference << endl; // difference is 8
}
```

the output is 8

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myInt = 100;

    int myInt2 = 0.5 * 17; // continue using a variable

    int myInt3 = myInt - myInt2;

    int difference = myInt - myInt3; // get the difference of the two numbers

    cout << difference << endl; // difference is 8 again!
}
```

the output is 8 again!

So my question is, if the math in the parentheses always comes first, then why am I getting different results? Shouldn't the first two trials have the same results as the second two trials? Another thing I should mention is that I have had these same results with other decimal numbers like 0.1 and 0.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does one double promote every int in the equation to double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663545/does-one-double-promote-every-int-in-the-equation-to-double)

Comment: Do you know what `int` means here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `0.5 * 17` results in a floating point value by virtue of the fact that one of its components, `0.5`, is floating point.

However, when you assign a floating point number like `8.5` to an integer, it's *truncated* to `8`. And, to be clear about this, it's truncated at the point of assignment.

So the first code segment calculates the value `100 + 8.5 = 108.5` and truncates that to `108` when you assign it to the integer<sup>(a)</sup>. The subtraction of `100` from that then gives you `8`.

In the second code segment, you calculate the value `100 - 8.5 = 91.5` and truncate that to `91` when assigning to the integer. The subtraction of that from `100` gives you `9`.

The reason the final two code segments work is because the `8.5` is being truncated *earlier* in `int myInt2 = 0.5 * 17`, *before* being added to or subtracted from `100`. In that case, `100 + 8 = 108` and `100 - 8 = 92`, both which are different from `100` by exactly `8` (sign notwithstanding).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It may help to think of it graphically:

```
int myInt2 = myInt + (0.5    * 17);
       ^     int   +  double * int
       |     \        \__________/
       |      \            |
       |       \         double
       |        \_____________/
       |                |
       +- truncate <- double
```

- The `0.5 * 17` is calculated first to give the floating point `8.5`.
- This is then added to the integer `myInt = 100` to give the floating point `108.5`.
- This is then truncated to `108` when being assigned to the integer `myInt2`.

Answer (score 1):

.5 * 17 is not 8, it is 8.5

```
int myInt = 100;

int myInt2 = myInt + (0.5 * 17);
```

This computes 100 + (0.5 * 17) or 108.5, which gets truncated to 108.

```
int difference = myInt2 - myInt;
```

This computes 108 - 100, or 8, which is the result you see.

In your second example:

```
int myInt = 100;

int myInt2 = myInt - (0.5 * 17);
```

This calculates 100 - 8.5, or 91.5, which gets truncated to 91.

```
int difference = myInt - myInt2;
```

This calculates 100 - 91, or 9.

In the same fashion you can work through the rest of your examples.

There's a very useful tool on your computer. It's called a "debugger". Using this tool you can step through any of your programs, one line at a time, and see for yourself the values of all variables at each step of the way.

Answer (score 0):

When doing maths with integers any decimal parts are lost AT EACH STEP.

So .5 * 17 gives 8.5, but the result stored in an integer variable is 8 which is used in subsequent steps, including output.