# Comparing uint8_t with a number

Tags: c++, c, keil

Maybe I do not understand C++ properly or is it a compiler's bug?

```
uint8_t a = 0x00;
uint8_t b = 0xFF;

if( a - b == 1 )
{
    doNothing();
}
```

doNothing is not called (as expected), because result of (a-b) was implicitly casted to the type of second operand in compare operation. And for numbers it's signed int. Okay.

```
if( a - b == (uint8_t)1 )
{
    doNothing();
}
```

doNothing STILL isn't called, but now I do not understand the reason for it! I have explicitly casted the number to uint8!

```
if( (uint8_t)(a - b) == 1 )
{
    doNothing();
}
```

Now doNothing is finally called, but again why? How can subtraction of two uint8 return an int?

Compiler is uVision ARMCC for ARM Cortex M3.

Comment: See this question for a more thorough explanation of the casting rules:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators

Comment: As I recall, Keil C is not fully conforming, and people have experienced considerable confusion because of it. In this case, though, it seems to be following the standard. BTW, why is this question tagged both C and C++? Which language are you using?

Comment: @Keith Thompson, I don't know language standarts that well and I thought that implicit casting rules could be different. So I checked it in both C and C++ (and for this bit it's the same).

Comment: @DaleWilson, I couldn't find anything about chars in there.

Comment: @Amomum exactly -- everything is automatically promoted to (at least) an int.

Comment: Not the issue, but there is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. A conversion that results from a cast is an explicit conversion. A conversion that the compiler does without a cast is an implicit conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker oh, I just thought that cast and conversion are synonims. Thanks for clearing that.

Comment: @Amomum, And by the way, even snippet #3 works, it is Undefined behavior, and you shouldn't dependency on it.

Comment: @ZijingWu, why is it undefined exactly? I can not cast signed int to uint8?

Comment: @Amomum， sorry my fault I just checked the standard, it is defined and result of the cast is 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `a - b`, the operands are promoted to `int` before the subtraction, so the result is -255, not 1.

That's why both the first and second examples fail; it's nothing to do with the other operand of `==`. The third converts -255 back to `uint8_t`, reducing it modulo 256, so the result is 1 as expected.

Comment: In the 3rd case, the `(uint8_t)(a - b)` results in a `(uint8_t) 1`.  Does this `1` then get promoted to an `int` to do the `bool operator == (int, int)`?

Comment: @chux: Yes, it does. All operands of built-in operators are promoted to at least `int`, or larger types if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

well I'm not the best when it comes to mathematics nor hex but it seems that `a = 0` and `b = 255` so it equals -255 not 1.

Answer (score 1):

ARM Cortex M3 is a 32 bit processor. So result of a - b is 0xFFFFFF01 which is not equal to 1 (1 ==> 0x00000001 in 32 bit representation) so doNothing() function is not called!

In case 2, if you typecast 1 to uint8_t, which is 0xFFFFFF01 is not equal to 0x01 so doNothing() function not called again!

In case 3, when you typecast a - b output to uint8_t then a - b result is 0x01 which is equal to 1, hence doNothing is called.

Comment: But why result of subtraction of two uint8_t is not uint8_t by default?

Comment: because of the 32 bit processor! in 32 bit processor all variables will of length 32 bit! by using uint8_t to a variable you will use only the lower 8 bits of that variable remaining 24 bits will be 0s. to make it understand in a easier way uint8_t typecast is equivalent of masking the 32 bit variable with (0x000000FF). in 32 bit process all the variables or constants is 32 bits in lenght! uint8_t will just tells how many bits you will use in those 32 bits! in your case a - b ==> 0x00000000 - 0x000000FF will results in 0xFFFFFF01. so if you typecast to uint8_t then result will be 0x00000001.

Comment: @Amomum Because the standard says so.  Types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (if they fit; otherwise to `unsigned`) before any binary operations.

Comment: I just do not understand, why result of this operation is not automatically casted back to uint8_t, why higher bits are not masked away. Just seems strange to me.

Comment: @JamesKanze, well, that's pretty much explains it. And even when I explicitly casted (uint8_t)1 - it still was casted to int?