# Function overloading resolution

Tags: c++, function

```
void f();
void f(int);
void f(int, int);
void f(double, double = 3.14);
f(5.6);  // calls void f(double, double) and not f(int) or f(), for that matter. Why?
```

I read that the compiler checks the number of parameters before checking the type of parameters. Then why aren't all the functions having different number of parameters getting eliminated?

Comment: Parameters for which no argument has been provided (at the call site) and which have default arguments are *ignored* for overload resolution [over.match.viable]/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does call `void f(double, double = 3.14);`, because of the default value for the second argument; one double provided, one required -> match. Otherwise, `void f(int);` would be selected. So its the number of *mandatory* parameters that matters.

Further info:

- Overload resolution: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution
- Implicit conversion rules: [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563000/1175253).

Comment: ADL? You mean overload resolution? This has nothing to do with name lookup.

Comment: @DyP: Thank you. As far as I know, it depends on the actual context, whether ADL is used additionally to a name lookup. It may be applied to gather other candidates for overload resolution. Mentioning ADL in conjunction with the OP's code snippet was misleading, so I removed that part.

Comment: "whether ADL is used additionally to a name lookup" ADL is a *form* of name lookup; it's always used when the function name is unqualified (qualified: `my_class_or_namespace::f`; unqualified: `f`). Btw you included the link to cppreference twice ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the second value from the function:

```
void f(double, double = 3.14);
```

So the call

```
f(5.6);
```

is like

```
f(5.6, 3.14);
```

use explicit type converting, to call the other function, like:

```
f((int)5.6);
```