# Type traits to get result of promotion from operator

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

[Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Lists the implicit type conversion for C++.

So the question is, is there a type trait that can do that table? something akin to

```
template <typename T, typename J>
struct promotion_type
{
  typedef decltype(operator+(const T&,const J&)) type;
};
```

(Not my question, but this doesn't compile:

```
/home/user/source/testdir/main.cpp:97:51: error: there are no arguments to 'operator+' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'operator+' must be available [-fpermissive]
   typedef decltype(operator+(const T&,const J&)) type;
                                               ^
/home/user/source/testdir/main.cpp:97:51: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<J>())`?

Comment: Interesting...i just used that to verify that std::common_type wasn't good enough.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The only difference is that bool, char, and short are all promoted to int by `+`, but not by common_type if T==J. The reference implementation of common_type is `decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<J>())`.