# RGB to greyscale conversion using CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

So I am trying to write a program that turns RGB images to greyscale.
I got the idea from the Udacity problem set. The problem is that when I write out the kernel in the Udacity web environment, it says my code works, however, when I try to do it locally on my computer, I get no errors, but my image instead of coming out greyscale, comes out completely grey. It looks like one grey box the dimensions of the image I loaded. Can you help me find the error in my code, I've compared it with the Udacity version and I can't seem to find it.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <string>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <iostream>



#define CUDA_ERROR_CHECK

#define CudaSafeCall( err ) __cudaSafeCall( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define CudaCheckError()    __cudaCheckError( __FILE__, __LINE__ )

inline void __cudaSafeCall(cudaError err, const char *file, const int line)
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
    if (cudaSuccess != err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSafeCall() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
            file, line, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
#endif

    return;
}

inline void __cudaCheckError(const char *file, const int line)
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
    cudaError err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaSuccess != err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaCheckError() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
            file, line, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }


    err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaSuccess != err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaCheckError() with sync failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
            file, line, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
#endif

    return;
}

__global__ void rgb_2_grey(uchar* const greyImage, const uchar4* const rgbImage, int rows, int columns)
{
    int rgb_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //x coordinate of pixel
    int rgb_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; //y coordinate of pixel

    if ((rgb_x >= columns) && (rgb_y >= rows)) {
        return;
    }

    int rgb_ab = rgb_y*columns + rgb_x; //absolute pixel position
    uchar4 rgb_Img = rgbImage[rgb_ab];
    greyImage[rgb_ab] = uchar((float(rgb_Img.x))*0.299f + (float(rgb_Img.y))*0.587f + (float(rgb_Img.z))*0.114f);
}
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void Proc_Img(uchar4** h_RGBImage, uchar** h_greyImage, uchar4 **d_RGBImage, uchar** d_greyImage);
void RGB_2_Greyscale(uchar* const d_greyImage, uchar4* const d_RGBImage, size_t num_Rows, size_t num_Cols);
void Save_Img();

Mat img_RGB;
Mat img_Grey;
uchar4 *d_rgbImg;
uchar *d_greyImg; 
int main()
{
        uchar4* h_rgbImg;
        //uchar4* d_rgbImge=0;
        uchar* h_greyImg;
        //uchar* d_greyImge=0;

        Proc_Img(&h_rgbImg, &h_greyImg, &d_rgbImg, &d_greyImg);
        RGB_2_Greyscale(d_greyImg, d_rgbImg, img_RGB.rows, img_RGB.cols);
        Save_Img();





    return 0;
}
void Proc_Img(uchar4** h_RGBImage, uchar** h_greyImage, uchar4 **d_RGBImage, uchar** d_greyImage){
    cudaFree(0);
    CudaCheckError();

    //loads image into a matrix object along with the colors in BGR format (must convert to rgb).
    Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Pictures\\wallpapers\\IMG_3581.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (img.empty()){
        cerr << "couldnt open file dumbas..." << "C:\\Users\\Austin\\Pictures\\wallpapers\\IMG_3581.JPG" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //converts color type from BGR to RGB
    cvtColor(img, img_RGB, CV_BGR2RGBA);

    //allocate memory for new greyscale image. 
    //img.rows returns the range of pixels in y, img.cols returns range of pixels in x
    //CV_8UC1 means 8 bit unsigned(non-negative) single channel of color, aka greyscale.
    //all three of the parameters allow the create function in the Mat class to determine how much memory to allocate
    img_Grey.create(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);

    //creates rgb and greyscale image arrays
    *h_RGBImage = (uchar4*)img_RGB.ptr<uchar>(0); //.ptr is a method in the mat class that returns a pointer to the first element of the matrix.
    *h_greyImage = (uchar*)img_Grey.ptr<uchar>(0);        //this is just like a regular array/pointer mem address to first element of the array. This is templated
                                                          //in this case the compiler runs the function for returning pointer of type unsigned char. for rgb image it is
                                                          //cast to uchar4 struct to hold r,g, and b values.

    const size_t num_pix = (img_RGB.rows) * (img_RGB.cols); //amount of pixels 

    //allocate memory on gpu
    cudaMalloc(d_RGBImage, sizeof(uchar4) * num_pix); //bites of 1 uchar4 times # of pixels gives number of bites necessary for array
    CudaCheckError();
    cudaMalloc(d_greyImage, sizeof(uchar) * num_pix);//bites of uchar times # pixels gives number of bites necessary for array
    CudaCheckError();
    cudaMemset(*d_greyImage, 0, sizeof(uchar) * num_pix);
    CudaCheckError();


    //copy array into allocated space
    cudaMemcpy(*d_RGBImage, *h_RGBImage, sizeof(uchar4)*num_pix, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    CudaCheckError();


    d_rgbImg = *d_RGBImage;
    d_greyImg = *d_greyImage; 
}


void RGB_2_Greyscale(uchar* const d_greyImage, uchar4* const d_RGBImage, size_t num_Rows, size_t num_Cols){

    const int BS = 16;
    const dim3 blockSize(BS, BS);
    const dim3 gridSize((num_Cols / BS) + 1, (num_Rows / BS) + 1); 

    rgb_2_grey <<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_greyImage, d_RGBImage, num_Rows, num_Cols);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); CudaCheckError();


}



void Save_Img(){

    const size_t num_pix = (img_RGB.rows) * (img_RGB.cols);
    cudaMemcpy(img_Grey.ptr<uchar>(0), d_greyImg, sizeof(uchar)*num_pix, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    CudaCheckError();


    imwrite("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Pictures\\wallpapers\\IMG_3581GR.JPG", img_Grey);

    cudaFree(d_rgbImg);
    cudaFree(d_greyImg);

}
```

**EDIT:** I realized that the local var in my main is the same name as the global var, I have edited the code here, now I get the error from visual studio that the

> variable `d_rgbIme` is being used without being initialized

when I have already initialized it above. If I set them equal to zero I get a CUDA error saying

> an illegal memory access was encountered

I tried running cuda-memcheck, but then I get the error that i could not run the file...

Comment: You're launching a grid of threads that is larger than your image.  But you have no thread-check in your kernel.  This means that some threads in your kernel will be accessing your image out-of-bounds.  Try adding a thread-check in your kernel like `if ((rgb_x < columns) && (rgb_y < rows)) {` before doing any reading or writing in your kernel.  Also try running your code with `cuda-memcheck`, and add [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your code.

Comment: You need to cast int to float before multiplication in (rgb_Img.x)*0.299f. Change it to (float(rgb_Img.x))*0.299f.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov that will happen [automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators).  It is not necessary to explicitly cast to `float`, when one of the multiplication arguments is already a `float` (0.299f is a `float` constant).

Comment: It's always better to cast types explicitly.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the comments. I have taken all you advice and implemented it into my code, unfortunately, it still doesn't run properly on my computer, only on Udacity's online enviroment.

Comment: Why don't you update the code posted in the question, to demonstrate the error checking you have added.  i.e. show the code you are currently using/trying.

Comment: Okay I have done so.

Comment: Did you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?  The one remaining error I can find in your code is that this kernel line: `if ((rgb_x >= columns) && (rgb_y >= rows)) {` should be this:  `if ((rgb_x >= columns) || (rgb_y >= rows)) {`  You want the thread to exit if either `x` *or* `y` is out of range.  && is boolean AND.  || is boolean OR.

Comment: HA!!! the `if ((rgb_x >= columns) || (rgb_y >= rows)) {` change did it!!

Comment: You should probably learn how to use `cuda-memcheck`, it's pretty simple.  This statement doesn't tell me much: "I tried running cuda-memcheck, but then I get the error that i could not run the file... "  What command line did you use to run cuda-memcheck, exactly?  What was the exact output?  If you answer those questions, you can probably learn how to use it and it will be useful for debugging CUDA programs.

Comment: cuda-memcheck <myfile> , the error i got was could not run <myfile>

Comment: I guess <myfile> is not an executable.  When I ask for the exact command line, and you say "cuda-memcheck <myfile>", I guess that is not the exact command line.  I guess you also haven't indicated the exact output.  It's difficult to help you that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the error thanks to one of the comments by Robert Crovella, he has been very helpful with this! it is in my kernel the if statement should read `if ((rgb_x >= columns) || (rgb_y >= rows)) {`

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same problem in JCUDA. See if you can use any part of this solution:

```
//Read Height and Width of image in Height & Width variables
int Width = image.getWidth();
int Height = image.getHeight();

int N = Height * Width;
int[] grayScale = new int[N];

//Allocate separate arrays to store Alpha, Red, Green and 
//Blue values for every pixel 
int[] redHost = new int[N];
int[] greenHost = new int[N];
int[] blueHost = new int[N];
int[] alphaHost = new int[N];

for(int i=0; i<Height; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<Width; j++)
    {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i);
        //Read the ARGB data
        alphaHost[i*Width+j] = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
        redHost[i*Width+j] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        greenHost[i*Width+j] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        blueHost[i*Width+j] = (pixel) & 0xff;
    }
}
```

/* Following are the CUDA Kernel parameters*/

```
Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to(
                                Pointer.to(new int[]{N}), //Total size of each array W * H 
                                Pointer.to(redDev),       // Pointer to redArray on device
                                Pointer.to(greenDev),     // Pointer to greenArray on device
                                Pointer.to(blueDev),      // Pointer to blueArray on device
                                Pointer.to(Output));      //Pointer to output array
```

/*Following is my RGBToGrayScale.cu..i.e. CUDA Kernel */

```
__global__ void RGBtoGrayScale(int N, int *red, int *green, int *blue, int *Output)
{
        int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(id<N)
    {
        Output[id] = (red[id]*0.2989) + (green[id]*0.587) + (blue[id]*0.114);
    }

}
```

/* Get the output data back to Host memory */

```
cuMemcpyDtoH(Pointer.to(grayScale), Output, N * Sizeof.INT);
```

/* Write the image with the new RBG values*/

```
BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(Width,Height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        WritableRaster raster = im.getRaster();
        for(int i=0;i<Height;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<Width;j++)
            {
                raster.setSample(j, i, 0, grayScale[i*Width+j]);
            }
        }
        try 
        {
            ImageIO.write(im,"JPEG",new File("glpattern.jpeg"));
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```