# K&R C Chapter exercise int to float?

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, types, type-conversion

Section 1.3 of Kernighan and Ritchie uses the following temperature conversion program to introduce For statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* print Fahrenheit-Celsius table */

int main(){

        int fahr;
        for (fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr + 20)
            printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
}
```

What it doesn't explain is how this program can make use of an int variable to produce float values without an error.  What makes this valid?  Don't all the variables in an equation have to be of the same type?  I'm hesitant to move forward without understanding this.

Comment: Please google search or search here itself. I believe this question has plenty of dupes already with sufficient exaplanations....

Comment: In a word, no. They do not have to be of the same type. Implicit type conversions can take place.

Comment: The language allows a lot of implicit conversions. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast.

Comment: The K&R book explains type conversion quite early on, I seem to recall it even includes a table of how implicit conversion happens. With that info, you should be able to work it out yourself

Answer (score 4):

The conversion are implicit, but enabling warnings should give you a message explaining that int is being converted to double.

Here `(5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32))`, a double is being multiplied by an int, and the int is converted to double using usual arithmetic conversions.

The types in arithmetic don't necessarily have to match. C has a whole chapter dedicated to conversions: 6.3 Conversions, 6.3.1 Arithmetic operands.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't: `(5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32)` is an expression of type `double`, **not** a `float`.

The reason being that 5.0 and 9.0 are `double` literals and the (fahr - 32) is *promoted* to that type before the multiplication takes place.

If you really want a `float` then use `(5.0f/9.0f)*(fahr-32)`. Note the suffixed `f` on the numbers (and you will need to suffix both).

`%f` is an appropriate format specifier in `printf` for a `double` and a `float`, so there are no problems there.

Answer (score 0):

In an arithmetic expression, if two operands are of different types (such as `int` and `double`), the operand with the lower precision will be converted to the same type as the operand with the higher precision.  The exact rules can be found in section 6.3.1.8 of the [online C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Note that this only applies for arithmetic (integer and floating-point) types, not for pointer or aggregate types.

Comment: Detail: "operand with the lower precision will be converted" is better as "operand with the lower rank will be converted".  With `double` (precision typically ~53 bits) and `long long`, the `long long` (precision typically ~63 bits) is converted to `double`, even though it has high precision.

Comment: @chux: yeah, "precision" wasn't the best term to use, but I couldn't think of a better one that didn't require a footnote that was longer than the actual answer.

Comment: True that "precision" is a decent approximation.  Could use [rank](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5563131/2410359)

Answer (score 0):

The reason an `int` can be promoted to a `double` without a problem -- assuming `int` represents a 32-bit integer and `double` represents a 64-bit IEEE floating point number, which is common -- is that a `double` has 53 bits of precision, so it has no trouble representing a 32-bit integer without loss. Any warning would just be informational and not a cause for concern, unlike when a 32-bit integer is coerced to a `float`, which only has 24 bits of precision and thus could lose up to eight bits (seven for a signed `int`) of precision in the cast.

Comment: Nit: "... up to 7 bits.".  ([`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) sign and 24 bits, `int`: sign and 31 bits)