# Mathematical Expressions into x86 Assembly Unsigned vs Unsigned

Tags: c++, assembly, unsigned, signed

I am writing an expression evaluator which produces x86 64bit assembly. I choose to mimic the C++ compiler rules for the variable types (char to int promotion etc., and literal values). However, I have an issue which is perplexing. When evaluating a complex mathematical expression, I use a postfix conversion first. Next, while tracking data types internally, the logic tracks data type according to conversion and or input operand types. My question is **when do signed numbers become unsigned and vice versa within intermediate representation by a C++ compiler**? During production of assembly, I noticed that clang assembly will sometimes use a movl when you might think that based upon previous data types the instruction would be to sign extended (movswl). *In general it is my desire to mimic the traditions of type conversion of a c++ compiler as well as during intermediate processing.*

As an example, consider this input into my program (the data types mimic c++):

```
short s_A=658
long long ll_B=293
unsigned int ui_C=94

print s_A
print ll_B
print ui_C
print "-------------------------"

ll_B=((394)-ui_C*(649)+(917)+ll_B-(80))
print ll_B


print "-------------------------"
print s_A
print ll_B
print ui_C
```

**whereas in C++ the same code is produced as:**

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 
short s_A=658;
long long ll_B=293;
unsigned int ui_C=94;

printf("%hi\n",s_A);
printf("%lld\n",ll_B);
printf("%u\n",ui_C);
printf("-------------------------\n");

ll_B=((394)-ui_C*(649)+(917)+ll_B-(80));
printf("%lld\n",ll_B);


printf("-------------------------\n");
printf("%hi\n",s_A);
printf("%lld\n",ll_B);
printf("%u\n",ui_C);

}
```

My logic produces the following assembly:

```
.section .data
LC1:
    .asciz "%hi\n"
LC2:
    .asciz "%lld\n"
LC5:
    .asciz "%s\n"
LC3:
    .asciz "%u\n"
LC4:
    .asciz "-------------------------"
ll_B:
    .quad 293
s_A:
    .word 658   # 
ui_C:
    .long 94    # 
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    and $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    finit
    mov s_A, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC1, %rdi
    call printf
    mov ll_B, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC2, %rdi
    call printf
    mov ui_C, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC3, %rdi
    call printf
    lea LC4, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC5, %rdi
    call printf
# Expression: ((394)-ui_C*(649)+(917)+ll_B-(80))
# Postfix: 394 ui_C 649 * - 917 + ll_B + 80 - 
# EVAL(1): ui_C*649
# MOVE ui_C ( UnsignedInt - 32bits ) to ( Int - 32bits  )
# instructionType=STATE_x86
    movl ui_C, %eax
    imull $649, %eax
# EVAL(2): 394-%eax
    movl $394, %ebx
    subl %eax, %ebx
# free register %eax
# EVAL(3): %ebx+917
    addl $917, %ebx
# EVAL(4): %ebx+ll_B
# CONVERT %ebx ( Int - 32bits ) to ( LongLong - 64bits  )
# instructionType=STATE_x86
    movslq %ebx, %rax  #ISSUE
    addq ll_B, %rax
# free register %ebx
# EVAL(5): %rax-80
    subq $80, %rax
# STORE RESULT :  %rax -> ll_B
# MOVE %rax ( LongLong - 64bits ) to ( LongLong - 64bits  )
# instructionType=STATE_x86
    movq %rax, ll_B
#
    mov ll_B, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC2, %rdi
    call printf
    lea LC4, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC5, %rdi
    call printf
    mov s_A, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC1, %rdi
    call printf
    mov ll_B, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC2, %rdi
    call printf
    mov ui_C, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    lea LC3, %rdi
    call printf
done:
    mov $0, %rdi
    call exit
```

**while gcc produces**

```
    .file   "whole_short_int_longlong_simple_33.cpp"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%hi\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%lld\n"
.LC2:
    .string "%u\n"
.LC3:
    .string "-------------------------"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movw    $658, -14(%rbp)
    movq    $293, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $94, -12(%rbp)
    movswl  -14(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $.LC3, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    imull   $649, %eax, %eax
    movl    $1311, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    subq    $80, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $.LC3, %edi
    call    puts
    movswl  -14(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**and clang produces:**

```
.text
    .file   "/home/anthony/comptest/simple/whole_short_int_longlong_simple/whole_short_int_longlong_simple_33.cpp"
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $64, %rsp
    movabsq $.L.str, %rdi
    movw    $658, -2(%rbp)          # imm = 0x292
    movq    $293, -16(%rbp)         # imm = 0x125
    movl    $94, -20(%rbp)
    movswl  -2(%rbp), %esi
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str1, %rdi
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    %eax, -24(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str2, %rdi
    movl    -20(%rbp), %esi
    movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str3, %rdi
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str1, %rdi
    movl    $394, %esi              # imm = 0x18A
    imull   $649, -20(%rbp), %ecx   # imm = 0x289
    subl    %ecx, %esi
    addl    $917, %esi              # imm = 0x395
    movl    %esi, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edx
    addq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
    subq    $80, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    %eax, -36(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str3, %rdi
    movl    %eax, -40(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str, %rdi
    movswl  -2(%rbp), %esi
    movl    %eax, -44(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str1, %rdi
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    %eax, -48(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movabsq $.L.str2, %rdi
    movl    -20(%rbp), %esi
    movl    %eax, -52(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %eax, -56(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $64, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Ltmp3:
    .size   main, .Ltmp3-main
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "%hi\n"
    .size   .L.str, 5

    .type   .L.str1,@object         # @.str1
.L.str1:
    .asciz  "%lld\n"
    .size   .L.str1, 6

    .type   .L.str2,@object         # @.str2
.L.str2:
    .asciz  "%u\n"
    .size   .L.str2, 4

    .type   .L.str3,@object         # @.str3
.L.str3:
    .asciz  "-------------------------\n"
    .size   .L.str3, 27


    .ident  "Ubuntu clang version 3.6.2-1 (tags/RELEASE_362/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.2)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Notice that the problem is within the evaluation of the rbx register (EBX=32). Because the last operands were literals, internally my logic notes these values as **signed int** 32bit. Therefore, when widening to 64bits, the **movslq** is emitted to sign extend the value. While gcc (c compiler rules), does a zero extend by moving the 32 bit data into another register (which zero fills the upper half), and then references it as a 64bit numeric.

There are two other problems which are a little more complex I also want to solve (carry, overflow (integer, SSE and FPU), unsigned/signed etc.), so if you are good in assembly on x86 64, I am a well behaved conversationalist. Researching the Internet does produce some results for issues relating this subject. However, I have not found a definitive encompassing text for these two's compliments comprehensions.

Comment: Do not add tags for unrelated languages. TL;DR. No need to post your whole program code. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Understand integer conversion rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules). The first link in google when searching for pretty much that term. You really must've exhausted yourself greatly while searching.

Comment: Technically, you only ask one question about the rules of integral type conversion in C++, and the rest of context. And that question is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators

Answer (score 0):

Section 4.5 explains how a value is converted to it's own type:

> 4.5 Integral promotions [conv.prom]
>
> - A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
>     int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>     the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
>     converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.
> - A prvalue of type char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t (3.9.1) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the following types that can
>     represent all the values of its underlying type: int, unsigned int,
>     long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int.
>     If none of the types in that list can represent all the values of its
>     underlying type, a prvalue of type char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t can
>     be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type.
> - A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the
>     following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration
>     (i.e., the values in the range b min to b max as described in 7.2):
>     int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or
>     unsigned long long int. If none of the types in that list can
>     represent all the values of the enumeration, a prvalue of an unscoped
>     enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of the extended integer
>     type with lowest integer conversion rank (4.13) greater than the rank
>     of long long in which all the values of the enumeration can be
>     represented. If there are two such extended types, the signed one is
>     chosen.
> - A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type.
>     Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying type,
>     a rvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>     fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying
>     type.
> - A prvalue for an integral bit-field (9.6) can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the
>     bit-field; otherwise, it can be converted to unsigned int if unsigned
>     int can represent all the values of the bit-field. If the bit-field is
>     larger yet, no integral promotion applies to it. If the bit-field has
>     an enumerated type, it is treated as any other value of that type for
>     promotion purposes.
> - A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.
> - These conversions are called integral promotions.

Section 5 of the C++ standard explains the promotion within expressions.

> ... lots of other things ...
>
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both
>     operands. [59] Then the following rules shall be applied to the
>     promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is
>       needed.
>   - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>       unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>       conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with
>       greater rank.
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>       greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand,
>       the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of
>       the operand with unsigned integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>       represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be
>       converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned
>       integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>       integer type.
>
> [59] As a consequence, operands of type bool, char16_t, char32_t,
>   wchar_t, or an enumerated type are converted to some integral type.

So, if we take your expression:

```
ll_B=((394)-ui_C*(649)+(917)+ll_B-(80));
```

Remove superfluous parenthesis so to read easier:

```
ll_B=394-ui_C*649+917+ll_B-80;
```

So, we have `394` - signed integer by section 4.5 rules. Then `ui_C*649` is an unsigned expression, `917` is a signed value (but adding it to a unsigned value of equal or greater size and fits in unsigned range), then `ll_B` is long-long. `80` is a signed integer.

As a summary, we should see:

- unsigned multiplication of `ui_C` with `649`.
- Subtracting that from 394.
- Adding 917 (unsigned).
- Unsigned extension to 64 bits.
- Adding `ll_B`
- Adding of `80`.

Comment: thanks Mat, I will take a closer look at the c standards document. Your explanation was very helpful. I noticed that you are invoking LLVM. Interesting expr.cpp module. I have not used it yet, I wanted my very own.