# How to get negative remainder with remainder operator on size_t?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, size-t

Consider the following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str("someString"); // length 10
    int num = -11;
    std::cout << num % str.length() << std::endl;
}
```

Running this code on http://cpp.sh, I get `5` as a result, while I was expecting it to be `-1`.

I know that this happens because the type of `str.length()` is `size_t` which is an implementation dependent unsigned, and because of the implicit type conversions that happen with binary operators that cause `num` to be converted from a `signed int` to an unsigned `size_t` (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873536/818849));
this causes the negative value to become a positive one and messes up the result of the operation.

One could think of addressing the problem with an explicit cast to `int`:

```
num % (int)str.length()
```

This might work but it's not guaranteed, for instance in the case of a string with length larger than the maximum value of `int`. One could reduce the risk using a larger type, like `long long`, but what if `size_t` is `unsigned long long`? Same problem.

How would you address this problem in a portable and robust way?

Comment: It's a remainder operator. The behaviour depends on which version of the standard you're using.

Comment: C code written before 1999 and C++ code written before 2011 may behave inconsistently in this case, since negative division/remainders were poorly specified in older standards. Make sure to use modern compilers/standards.

Comment: While size_t may be represented as long long, I doubt it will ever max out. Unless your platform supports exa-byte string length that is... Which I think is a reasonable restriction in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, you can just cast the result of `length` to `std::string::difference_type`.

To address *"But what if the size is too big?"*:

That won't happen on 64 bit platforms and even if you are on a smaller one: When was the last time you actually had a string that took up more than half of total RAM? Unless you are doing really specific stuff (which you would know), using the `difference_type` is just fine; quit fighting ghosts.

Alternatively, just use `int64_t`, that's certainly big enough. (Though maybe looping over one on some 32 bit processors is slower than `int32_t`, I don't know. Won't matter for that single modulus operation though.)

(Fun fact: Even some prominent committee members consider littering the standard library with unsigned types a mistake, for reference see 
[this panel](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything) at 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50 )

Pre C++11, the sign of `%` with negative values was implementation defined, for well defined behavior, use [`std::div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) plus one of the casts described above.

Comment: Thanks for the insight about `difference_type`. If I understand correctly, by the standard, `size_t` is large enough to represent the length of the string, while `difference_type` is large enough to represent the largest possible difference between two iterators on the same string; since the maximum difference is the length of the string, then it should always be safe to cast `size_t` to `difference_type`. Correct?

Comment: *"`difference_type` is large enough to represent the largest possible difference between two iterators on the same string;"* In reality this pretty much holds, but it's not guaranteed. On a 32 bit system, both `size_t` and the difference type will most likely be 32 bit integers, so if the string is like 2.5GB or bigger, the size won't fit in the signed one.

Answer (score 3):

We know that

```
-a % b == -(a % b)
```

So you could write something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
constexpr T safeModulo(T a, T2 b)
{
    return (a >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * static_cast<T>(std::llabs(a) % b);
}
```

This won't overflow in 99.98% of the cases, because consider this

```
safeModulo(num, str.length());
```

If `std::size_t` is implemented as an `unsigned long long`, then `T2 -> unsigned long long` and `T -> int`.

As pointed out in the comments, using `std::llabs` instead of `std::abs` is important, because if `a` is the smallest possible value of `int`, removing the sign will overflow. Promoting `a` to a `long long` just before won't result in this problem, as `long long` has a larger range of values.

Now `static_cast<int>(std::llabs(a) % b)` will always result in a value that is smaller than `a`, so casting it to `int` will never overflow/underflow. Even if `a` gets promoted to an `unsigned long long`, it doesn't matter because `a` is already "unsigned" from `std::llabs(a)`, and so the value is unchanged (i.e. didn't overflow/underflow).

Because of the property stated above, if `a` is negative, multiply the result with `-1` and you get the correct result.

---

The only case where it results in undefined behavior is when `a` is `std::numeric_limits<long long>::min()`, as removing the sign overflows `a`, resulting in undefined behavior. There is probably another way to implement the function, I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but won't this lead to undefined behaviour if a is `INT_MIN`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs

Comment: @elnigno True, I completely forgot about that case. Promoting `a` to `long long` will result in defined behavior. Thanks :)