# Squaring a number in C++ yields wrong value

Tags: c++

If I do

```
 int n = 100000;
 long long x = n * n;
```

then `x == 1410065408`

1410065408 is 2^31, yet I expect x to be 64 bit

What is going on?
 I'm using VSC++ ( default VS c++ compiler )

Comment: You may want to read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aetzh118.aspx

Comment: Aside: if you need a 64-bit type, you should usually prefer `int64_t` to `long long`. Similarly, if you need a 32-bit type, you should prefer `int32_t` to `int`. (aside #2: `int` isn't actually guaranteed to be 32 bits! It could be, for example, 64 bits or 16 bits, or even something exotic like 37 bits. Although I think MSVC insists on 32 bits)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`n*n` is too big for an `int` because it is equal to `10^10`. The (erroneous) result gets stored as a `long long`.

Try:

```
long long n = 100000;
long long x = n*n;
```

Here's [an answer that references the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873536/2124148) that specifies that the operation `long long x = (long long)n*n` where `n` is an int will not cause data loss. Specifically,

> If both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.

Since the functional cast has the highest precedence here, it converts the left multiplicand to a `long long`. The right multiplicand of type `int` gets converted to a `long long` according to the standard. No loss occurs.

Comment: I think by small you mean big

Comment: So it first multiplies both the integers into an int and after that it assigns it into a long so the overflowed value gets assigned, got it.

Comment: @Chris Yes, but you don't need to declare n as 64bit you can simple cast one of n to long long like `long long x = (long long)n*n;`

Comment: Logman's comment is a good one, but I personally prefer `long x = n*(long long)n;` for conveying that the cast happens before the multiplication without having to remember precedence rules.

Comment: > Multiplication occurs before assignment.
But there's no assignment </pedantic>

Comment: Nitpicking a little but this has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Initialization occurs. Mistakes were made.

Comment: Even if it were an assignment, you'd be have pressed to convince me that this was ultimately caused by operator precedence. At the very least, it would not be caused _only_ by operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring n as a long long is the best solution as mentioned previously.

Just as a quick clarification to the original post, 1410065408 is not 2^31, the value comes about as follows:

100,000 ^ 2 = 10,000,000,000 which exists in binary form as:

10 0101 0100 0000 1011 1110 0100 0000 0000

C++ integers are strictly 32 bits in memory. Therefore, the front two bits are ignored and the value is stored in memory as binary:

0101 0100 0000 1011 1110 0100 0000 0000

In decimal, this is equal to exactly 1410065408.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - This is another solution to the problem; what this will do is cast the integer values to a long long before the multiplication so you don't get truncation of bits.

**Original Posting**

```
int n = 100000;
long long x = static_cast<long long>( n ) * static_cast<long long>( n );
```

**Edit** - The original answer provided by Jossie Calderon was already accepted as a valid answer and this answer adds another valid solution.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question ("*why* is it caused?"), it is another solution to the exercise.

Comment: @Chris probably it will produce exactly same code as what I suggested, it is just more formal. `static_cast` can have nice benefits if you use it right but for your purpose there is no need to make it so long. And you don't need to cast all parameters only one.

Comment: When in doubt use the casting modifiers; `static_cast<>(), dynamic_cast<>(), reinterpret_cast<>(), etc.`

Comment: @JossieCalderon Correct; this question already had an accepted answers so there was no reason to go back and explain it all over again; so I just provided another possible solution to the same problem.