# C++ function returning wrong data type

Tags: c++, function, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

The round() seems to return a wrong data type value in the following code. This is apparent from the error thrown by the compiler when I remove all long long casts in line 50 (The else statement).
What could be the reason?

The error encountered during compilation:-

> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
>   C:\Users\MUNNU\Desktop\KBIGNUMB.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>   C:\Users\MUNNU\Desktop\KBIGNUMB.cpp|50|error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

The program code:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

long long modexp(long long n,long long p,long long m)
{
    if(p==0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        long long z=modexp(n,p/2,m);
        if(p%2)
            return (((z*z+m)%m)*n+m)%m;
        else return (z*z+m)%m;
    }
}

long long round(long double a)
{

    long long z=((long long)(a+0.5));
    return z;
}

long long digits(long long a)
{
    long long c=0;
    while(a!=0)
    {
        a/=10;
        //cout<<a<<endl;
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    long long a,n,m;
    for(register int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin>>a>>n>>m;
        //cout<<(long long)(((long long)((pow(100,n)-1)/99)%m)*(a%m))%m<<endl<<(pow(100,n)-1)/99<<endl<<(((100*100-1)/99)*a)%m<<endl<<'@'<<((long long)(pow(10,floor(log10(a*10)))+0.5)-1)<<'@'<<endl;
        if(a==0)
            cout<<0<<endl;
        else
        //cout<<"p"<<digits(11)<<'@';
        {
            long double y=pow(10,digits(a));
            long long x=(modexp(round(y),n,m*round(y-1))-1+(m*(long long)round(y-1)));
            cout<<(((a+m)%m)*(((x%(m*(long long)round(y-1)))/((long long)round(y-1))+m)%m)+m)%m<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Break this up into something readable `cout<<(((a+m)%m)*((((modexp(round(pow(10,digits(a))),n,m*round(pow(10,digits(a))-1))-1+(m*(long long)round(pow(10,digits(a))-1)))%(m*(long long)round(pow(10,digits(a))-1)))/((long long)round(pow(10,digits(a)))-1)+m)%m)+m)%m<<endl;`

Comment: Holy expression batman.  How about using some variables to store the different pieces of it?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Rewriting it so it's readable isn't just about getting it to work (although it might help); it's about making it easier for readers (including you) to understand.

Comment: `round()` already returns `long long` why do you explicitly cast it to that type? To make it even more unreadable?

Comment: That's the actual problem. round() should ideally return long long, but this code works only when I explicitly cast it to long long which does not make sense.

Comment: @Slava See the comments under the answer.  `round` is probably `std::round` and not the OP's thanks to `using namespace std;`

Comment: Looks like you could make the code more readable and efficient by storing the result of `pow(10,digits(a))` into a temporary variable.  This would calculate once versus at least 3 times in your posted code.

Comment: Also, looks like your manipulating digits of a number for an online judge.  IMO, digit manipulation is easier when the number is kept in string form.  Accessing a digit is easy as `value = number_as_text[digit_position] - '0';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `round()` with double agrument you actually call:

```
double round(double x);
```

from `<cmath>` not your version hence the error. If you rename your function error would be gone without cast. Yet another reason to avoid `using namespace std`.

Comment: Understood. I thought std::round() returns an int. Then, my program should have worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite clear.

> error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

The modulo operation is not defined for doubles.

Your giant expression uses [std::pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) which only handles floating point types. When you call `std::pow` with an integer, it's promoted to a floating point type. The result is then also a floating point type. Then, when preforming arithmetic operations on a mix of `double` and integers, the integers are promoted to `double` (see [this summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5563131/7359094) of promotion rules) so the result is also `double`. This means that, without all those casts, large portions of that expression is treated as `double`. Eventually, you preform a modulo operation between two of those parts, which is not supported.

Comment: It's hard to read but every call to `pow` is done as a parameter to `round` which does return an integer type.

Comment: This answer is totally wrong. I know that and that's why I have used the round() to convert the double returned by pow() to a long long.

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi `round` return the same type as it's parameter, not `long long`. `lround` and `llround` return integers.

Comment: Ha.  Just one more reason to not use `using namespace std;`.  Didn't even see that the first time.  @ShubhamAvasthi What happens if you get rid of `using namespace std;` and change all your calls to `pow` to `std::pow`?

Comment: I didn't know that the std::round() returns a double. I thought it would return an int. Then, my program should have worked correctly.

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi You might expect `round` to return an integer, as by definition the result contains no decimals. But consider that `double` is not only used to represent decimals, but also for very large values which are not representable by typical integers. For example, `round(1e100)` can't be represented by a 64 bit integer.