# Why does this if conditional with string.length() evaluate inconsistently?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main()
{
    std::string string = "hi";

    std::cout << "Enter index: ";
    int index;
    std::cin >> index;

    if(index < string.length())
        std::cout << index << " is less than " << string.length();
    else
        std::cout << index << " is greater than " << string.length();
}
```

The string length is 2. When I enter in a negative number, say -3, the if statement evaluates to false and executes else statement & prints *-3 is greater than 2*.  If I enter in a positive number still less than the string length, say 1, if statement evaluates to true & prints *1 is less than 2*.

Question:

**So while -3 and 1 are both numbers less than string.length(), why is it that only 1 evaluate to true whereas -3 does not in this if statement?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Comment: `string.length()` is unsigned so the other operands will be promoted to `unsigned` as well. `-3` converted to an `unsigned` value is a very large number.

Comment: Don't spam tags! C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: return type of `string.length()` is `string::size_type`.  `string::size_type` is `Alloc::size_type`. (`Alloc` is `allocator`) `Alloc::size_type` is `size_t`. `size_t` is unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare an `int` with an `unsigned int`, the `int` converts to `unsigned int`. So if it was a negative value before, it becomes a very big positive integer. That is why it becomes larger than the size of the string.

Try doing this:

```
 unsigned int x = 100;
 int y = -1;

 std::cout << (x < y? "Yes" : "No" << std::endl; //prints Yes

 std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(y) << std::endl; //prints big +ve number
```

Note that the `std::string::size()` and `std::string::length()` both returns `std::string::size_type` which is just an alias of *some* `unsigned` integral type, could be `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `size_t`(which is usually an alias again of some `unsigned` integral type).

Comment: thank you so much for this explanation. I really appreciate it sir.

Answer (score 1):

try this

because .length or .size is an unsigned int, the regular int is automatically converted. Store it in a variable of int data type and this should solve your problem.

```
int main()
{
    std::string string = "hi";

    std::cout << "Enter index: ";
    int index;
    int length = string.size();
    std::cin >> index;

    if(index < length)
        std::cout << index << " is less than " << string.length();
    else
        std::cout << index << " is greater than " << string.length();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. it indeed did work. Just couldn't wrap my head around why that would work, but now I see why.