# Implicit conversion: is the following warning valid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, bit-shift, integer-promotion, unsigned-long-long-int

This question [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators) (and several others) state

> If either is long long unsigned int the other is promoted to long long
>   unsigned int

However if I do the following under MSVC:

```
unsigned int a = <some expression>;
unsigned long long b = a << 32ULL;
```

The second line generates the following warning:

```
warning C4293: '<<': shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

`32ULL` is a 64 bit unsigned value, therefore according to the implicit conversion rules this should mean that `a` is converted to `unsigned long long` as well.  Hence I'm shifting a 64 bit value by 32 bits, clearly a well defined operation.

Is MSVC bugged or is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: Shifts are special.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015.  That said, I'm 99.9% certain that we got the same warning from VS 2010 before upgrading, and a quick test with VS 2017 also gives the same warning.

Comment: This needs the language lawyer tag. This is the subtle difference between 'usual arithmetic conversions' and 'integral promotions'. They're different things but both happen and both may convert values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shifts don't do the so-called "usual arithmetic conversions", which is the rules you cited. [They only perform integral promotions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.shift#1.sentence-2). The result of a shift is of [the same type as the promoted left operand](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.shift#1.sentence-3).

Comment: Could one get around the issue, by doing the assignment from a to b, then shifting b?