# Does adding a .0 after integer have any effect on division?

Tags: c++

I took a programming test, and my teacher took points off for diving by 3 instead of 3.0 , even though it appears I get the same answer.

```
volu = PI*(BASE*BASE)*(HEIGHT/3);
```

Does the .0 even matter in a c++ program, if so why?
Thank you!

EDIT: I used doubles for PI and BASE

Comment: What type is `HEIGHT`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Comment: All are doubles

Answer (score 2):

(For what it's worth I find the way you have it to be rather prudent.)

If `HEIGHT` was an integral type then it would have been *absolutely essential* that you wrote `3.0` rather than `3`. (`3.0` is a literal of type `double`, cf. `3` which is an `int`.)

Otherwise the division would have taken place in *integer arithmetic*, causing the result to go off.

Personally I'd remove all the redundant parentheses and write it as

```
PI * BASE * BASE * HEIGHT / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two integers will be divided using euclidean division. Adding the .0 changes it into a normal division, because you're no longer dividing two integers but an integer and a double.