# C++ string size minus integer is not the expected value, why?

Tags: c++

```
int main () {
string s = "";
cout << s.size() << endl;
cout << s.size() - 5 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The above code output is following:

```
0
18446744073709551611
```

Why the second result is not -5?

Comment: As described in the documentation: [std::string::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), which is "unsigned integer type". Unsigned integers don't have negative values.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators "Otherwise, if either operand is unsigned, the other shall be converted to unsigned. "

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::string::size()` returns a value of type `std::string::size_type` which is an unsigned integer type (no, this is not guaranteed to be `unsigned int`, use `std::size_t` (`<cstddef>`)). To perform the subtraction both operand values undergo integral promotion by which both values are promoted to a common type - in this case `std::string::size_type`, then the subtraction is performed.

[Integral Promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)

Comment: So in this question, the `s.size() - 5`, `s.size()` is promoted to int type? Why it not 0, but a large number value.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns an *unsigned* integer type. Underflow of unsigned type is well-defined and causes the result to wrap around, starting at the maximum value that the type can represent.

Comment: and `unsigned - int` is also `unsigned`.