# Cython giving 'unnecessary' warning

Tags: python, warnings, cython, unsigned

The following cython script, results in `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions` warning.

```
%%cython
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector as cpp_vec
import numpy as np

cdef cpp_vec[long] a  = np.array([1,2,3], np.int)
cdef Py_ssize_t i

for i in range(a.size()):        # Using a.size() as parameter of range() causes the warning
    pass
```

Is this warning necessary? If so, why? Also, is it possible to silence these unsigned vs signed comparison warnings?

Also, why only the first `for` loop results in the warning?

```
%%cython
cdef:
    ssize_t i
    unsigned long m = 10
    unsigned int n = 10
    long o = 10

for i in range(m):
    pass
for i in range(n):
    pass
for i in range(o):
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by „cython script results in warning“? Do you see the warning while generating c code, while compiling or while loading/running the resulting module?

Comment: I would say during compiling. However, I am not exactly sure how to differentiate between generating C code and compile time warnings. There are no warnings while running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning from your g++-compiler, and as every compiler-warning should be taken seriously.

The for-loop of your Cython code is transformed to the following/similar cpp-code:

```
 std::vector<long>::size_type __pyx_t_7;
 Py_ssize_t __pyx_t_8;
 __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_v_xxxx_a.size();
 for (__pyx_t_8 = 0; __pyx_t_8 < __pyx_t_7; __pyx_t_8+=1) {
     ....
 }
```

The problem is, that `std::vector<long>::size_type` is 64bit unsigned integer ona  64-bit system, and `Py_ssize_t` a 64bit signed integer.

C++ uses implicit conversion for built-in types, in order to be able to evaluate `__pyx_t_8 < __pyx_t_7`, the rules can be found for example in this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5563131/5769463).

There are multiple reason, why this warning makes sense - the rules are quite complicated and experience has shown, that programmers often handle them wrong. For example `-1<1U` evaluates to `false` (see [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb96547f976f8c96)), but

```
signed char a =-1;
unsigned char b = 1;
std::cout<<(a<b)<<"\n";
```

prints `1`, i.e. `(a<b)` evaluates to `true` (see [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ab1cb44ed301bfa)). Such quirks can easily leads to hard-to-find bugs.

Even more, historically, before the standard was established, different compilers handled those conversions differently - when switching to a different compiler, it was a nice thing to see all the places where the behavior could be changed - but this not really important nowdays.

There are different strategies to avoid this warning.

**1. Go with the flow:**

Isn't easier to make the `i` a `size_t` instead of `Py_ssize_t`, i.e `cdef size_t i`?

**2. Cast and check:**

You can explicitly cast and then check, whether the assumptions are OK, e.g.

```
...
cdef Py_ssize_t i

cdef Py_ssize_t n = <Py_ssize_t>(a.size())
if n<0 :
    raise ValueError("too big");

for i in range(n):
...
```

The above becomes fast quite cumbersome, so one usually extract this into a utility-function.

**3. Just cast:**

One could ask "how probable it is that a vector has more than `2^63` entries?" and just skip the checking:

```
...
for i in range(<Py_ssize_t>(a.size())):        
    print(i)
```

and then... see the code fail 30 years later:)

**4. Disable compiler warning:**

One also could pass `-Wno-sign-compare`-option to the compiler via `extra_compile_args` in setup-file or `-c=-Wno-sign-compare` in IPython, which would turn off the warning in the whole code. It is probably safer to use the "Just cast"-solution, which mutes the warning only at this one place and not everywhere.

---

The warning is not issued if signed integer is of larger size than the unsigned integer: In this case the unsigned integer is converted to larger signed integer and fits into positive range of the larger type.

For example `ssize_t` has 64bit and `unsigned int` has 32bit, thus 32bit-unsigned bit is converted to 64bit-`ssize_t` before the comparison - the will be no overflow, because positive numbers up to 63 can be represented by `ssize_t´.

Comment: Since, the warning is caused because of range(), I don't think strategy 1 would work.

Comment: @ManishGoel `range(N)` will be translated by Cython to a simple for-loop (and has nothing to do with Python's range) and `N` is used as upper bound without changing its type. Just try it out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Using `ssize_t` works. But, `range (or the C `for` loop) seems to be having trouble with unsigned long. I have edited the question with the test case.

Comment: @ManishGoel I have added an explanation for `ssize_t` vs `unsigned int` (because I think it makes the answer better), but you should read about chameleon questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions