# What is type if uint8_t value multiplied by uint8_t

Tags: c++

What is type if `uint8_t` value multiplied by `uint8_t`? For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 'a', b = 'b';
    std::cout << a * b;
}
```

The output of the program is **9506**. Will `a * b` be `uint32_t` type data?
Why not still be a `uint8_t` type?
Thanks.

Comment: The smallest integer type that a C++ program evaluates expressions with is `int`. Any smaller type `sizeof(uint_8) < sizeof(int)` will cause the values to be promoted before the operation. The result of an operation is always the same types as the input value (in this case after promotion). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5563131/14065 Ther last case applies `Both operands are promoted to int`

Comment: Incidentally, the result of multiplying two 8-bit values will fit in 16 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [integer promotion](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGNzdGRpbnQ+CgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKICAgIHVpbnQ4X3QgYSA9ICdhJywgYiA9ICdiJzsKICAgIFtbbWF5YmVfdW51c2VkXV0gYXV0byByID0gYSAqIGI7Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp2a&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0) rules in C++ integer types narrower than `int` in usual arithmetic operations are promoted to `int` before the operation is applied (simplified explanation).

You can observe this at [https://cppinsights.io/](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGNzdGRpbnQ+CgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKICAgIHVpbnQ4X3QgYSA9ICdhJywgYiA9ICdiJzsKICAgIFtbbWF5YmVfdW51c2VkXV0gYXV0byByID0gYSAqIGI7Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp2a&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0) (neat tool right?):

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 'a', b = 'b';
    [[mayebe_unsued]] auto r = a * b; // <-- pay attention here
}
```

is converted internally by the compiler to:

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
  uint8_t a = static_cast<unsigned char>('a');
  uint8_t b = static_cast<unsigned char>('b');
  int r = static_cast<int>(a) * static_cast<int>(b); // <-- pay attention here
}
```

As to why, well, it was considered wayback that operations with operands in the platform native type (`int`) are faster than with operands with narrower types. I honestly don't know how much truth is to this in modern architectures.

Comment: Note: Remember the `as if` rule. If the value was assigned back to `unint8_t` and multiplication of `uint8_t` was faster than int the compiler could use this as the observable result would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that `uint8_t` is being [promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to `int`, because everything smaller than `int` is converted into an `int` before they can be multiplied / added / etc.

You cannot stop this, but you can cast it back (By assigning it to a `uint8_t` variable or casting it as `static_cast<uint8_t>(a * b)`)