# How to return a double from Integer division in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a piece of code in C++. My question would be how can one return 1.5 as a result instead of 1 from the following code.

```
double avg(int, int);
int main ()
{
    double average= avg(2, 1);
    cout << average;
}

double avg(int num1, int num2)
{
    double average = (num1 + num2)/2;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: cat both `int`eger to `double` explicitly..?

Comment: [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563000/14065)

Answer (score 4):

Just make at least one of them a `double`:

```
 double average = (num1 + num2)/2.0; // note 2.0 is a double
```

This will allow [implicit conversion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-in-c/) to happen and convert everything to a `double`.