# Conditionally choose a type with decltype() and the ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I have a file *a.cpp*:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=5;
    double b=4.3;
    decltype(a>b?a:b) n;
    cout << typeid(n).name();   
}
```

The Output of above Code is **`d`** but I expect it to be **`i`** as "a" is greater than "b"

I am trying to learn about decltype. Can you please tell what I am missing here?

I am using gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1).

Comment: It doesn't matter what's greater, the type of the expression is double either way.

Comment: C++ is a statically-typed language.

Comment: What you want would only work if the two arguments are constexpr, [like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/293fe0a38c8c8997), I fail to see the use case though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Comment: `template<class T1, class T2> auto max(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a>b?a:b) { return a>b?a:b;}`

how does this  code work then?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: @tkausl Write your answer in the answer section please

Comment: [The type and value category of the conditional expression `E1 ? E2 : E3` are determined according to the following rules: ...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)

Comment: @PrashantKumarNirmal That function causes undefined behavior if it is called with arguments of the same type and its return value (which will be a reference to one of the parameters out-of-their lifetime) is used. You should not use it. You need to remove the trailing return type to make it behave correctly. In either case, it returns a compile-time fixed type, determined by the rules that are described, e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Comment: @Borgleader I don't think it's a duplicate of *that* question, because this one asks about conditionally selecting a type and not about int/float type promotion. The essence of this question will remain the same if you convert one of the types to a struct type, and the other question is not about this.

Comment: As an aside, regarding the thing that @walnut describes, this is true and it's the reason that I (and many others) feel that C++ is just completely out of control for the average user. It really should not be that trivial to get silent, yet critical, bugs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Clang gives a [warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/V7wiEu), at least. Surprisingly, GCC does not.

Comment: @Al.G. I added that duplicate after OP posted a comment asking why the type of the expression was always double (that comment seems to have since been removed).

Comment: That's why we don't vote-to-close-as-duplicate based on comments, but on the actual content of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a statically-typed language.

That means, the type of a thing cannot depend on runtime criteria.

For this reason, the expression `a>b?a:b` will always evaluate to a value of the same type. That's part of the rules of the conditional operator.

In this case, the "mutually compatible type" (I have made this term up) is `double`, so you will always get a `double` (see the rules [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)).

If `a` wins the condition, it's converted from `int` to `double`, except in `decltype` your code is an "unevaluated context" (because nothing at runtime can possibly influence the outcome), so the condition isn't even performed, only the possible resulting type is calculated, from the types of the arguments to the conditional operator. If there were multiple possible resulting types, then the code would be ambiguous and your program would not be compilable.

You can get this behaviour with magic like `std::variant`, but consider whether you *really* need/want it.

Comment: `template<class T1, class T2> auto max(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a>b?a:b) { return a>b?a:b;}` 

how does this code work then?

Comment: @PrashantKumarNirmal It doesn't.