# How to correct this arithmetic operation without the need to use fmod?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In `c++` this code below shows an error:

```
expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
illegal left operand has type 'double'
```

is it possible to correct it without the need to use `fmod`?

```
# include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 6, z = 4;
    float w = 3.5, c;
    c = (y + w - 0.5) % x * y;   // here is the error
        cout << "c = " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: switch it to `int` first?

Comment: Could you comment on what you expect `(y + w - 0.5) % x * y` to do?

Comment: I did and the output is 9 in the compiler, and the calculator shows 24!

Comment: What do you think the `%` operator do?

Comment: @silverfox the error does not go until i apply `fmod` to it even after changing `c` to `int`

Comment: @Brian I expect it to be 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [type casting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) to fix it :

```
c = ((int) (y + w - 0.5)) % x * y;
```

To clarify your response in the comments, changing `c` to type `int` still don't work as the part `(y + w - 0.5)` is not evaluated as `int` but as `double`. And [modulus operation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/modulus) doesn't take that type as an argument.

Full modified code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 6, z = 4;
    float w = 3.5, c; //c could still stayed as float
    c = ((int) (y + w - 0.5)) % x * y; //swapped out here
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;
}
```

Output : `c = 24`.

To be clear here, this is only a temporary fix for this case, when you know `(y + w - 0.5)` is going to have a clear integer value. If the value is something like `0.5` or `1.447`, [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) is desirable.

Here's a post on type conversion rules in an expression regarding interaction between `float/double` and `int/long long` : [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Comment: @sweenish gotta fix that, thanks!